# javascript inside html, correct references

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following html code with js inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculate Payments Form</title>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function calcpayments()
        <script>
        function calcpayments()

        {
        var r_buch=document.forms[0].buch.value*1;

        var r_a=document.forms[0].a.value*1;
        var r_lbh=document.forms[0].lbh.value*1;
        var r_steuer=document.forms[0].steuer.value*1;
        var r_rev=document.forms[0].rev.value*1;
        var r_jr=document.forms[0].jr.value*1;


        var result=((r_buch)+(40*r_a*r_lbh)+(r_steuer*400)+(r_rev*(2000))+(r_jr*1000));

        result=(Math.max(Math.round(result/12),80));

        document.getElementById("monthlypayment").innerHTML=result;

        }

        </script>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="margin-left: 100px;"> 
<h3>Unverbin</h3>

<div align="left">
<div id="calclpayment">
        <form>
        <strong>
          <br />
Bitte f</strong> <br />
<br />
<table width="100%" align="left">
          <td width="176"><div align="left">Anzahl </div></td>
              <td width="144"><input type= "text" name="buchungen" /></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div align="left">Anz</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mitarbeiter"/>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="58"></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">+ Lohnb:</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="lbh">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">+ Steuer:</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="steuer">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">+ ein</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="rev">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">+ Jahres</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="jr">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Input" type="button" value="Preis berechnen" onclick="calcpayments()"/></td>
        <td><input name="reset2" type="reset" value="Löschen" /></td>
      </tr>
          </table>
   <br />
  <b>Un</b>  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="monthlypayment" style="font-size: 25px;background-color:#1b365d;
font-weight: bold; width: 100px; padding: 5px; color:#FFF;" > 0  </div>
      </form>

  </div>
          <br />
          <br />
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works in a separate html file. Now I want to integrate it to an other html file. Sorry, but I am beginner.. :) I am just taking this code 1:1 and adding to the other html file. Html format is all ok, but the js is not working. Could someone help? I think the problem are the references of the js?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the JS. Depending on how the JS is written, it might help to put the script tag at the bottom of the body instead of the head.

Comment: I edited the JS in the question above, thanks

Comment: The edit does not show the code, so it is still difficult for the community to offer insight/direction. Including a skeleton HTML document with `placeholder code` and `placeholder html` where the real meat and potatoes should be does not give us any additional information. We can already assume a structure along those lines. You mention you believe the "references of the JS" are a problem. Have you checked the developer console of your browser to verify the JavaScript file is resolving successfully? The instructions to do so will vary based on your browser - search engines are your friend.

Comment: thanks for this tip. in Opera it shows: TypeError: document.forms[0].buch is undefined. In Edge : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at calcpayments (blog.html:174)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (blog.html:252)

Comment: I don't see an element identified by "buch" in the code snippet you've provided. The closest I see is an element with the name `buchungen`. This seems like one of:
# The issue noted in my answer
# A bad reference (`buch` -> `buchungen`)
# The actual document structure (eg. the number and/or order of forms) differ from what the JavaScript expects. It's typically considered general practice to use more affirmative selectors over indices and property accessors.

Comment: Why is there a `<script>` tag inside `function calcpayments()`?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the immediate invocation of your function, it seems as though your JavaScript file is loading before the document is ready. Consider either placing your `script` tag at the bottom of the body, or listening to the [Document `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).